# Should we use [interactive-functions] or [commands]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Obviously the two tags should be made synonyms, I'm asking which one
we should use. @Drew recently pointed to me, we had a question tagged
as [interactive-command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive-command), which is obviously a pleonasm.

I've changed that tag to [commands](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commands), but I'm wondering if
[interactive-functions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive-functions) would be better. Or do we not need such a
tag at all?

Comment: I would say that "commands" is the most appropriate Emacs terminology (and nicer to read), and "interactive-functions" would be a useful synonym for people who start typing "interactive".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The tag should be `commands`.**  It could have `interactive-function` as a synonym, but I doubt that that will prove useful at all.

`interactive` is a Lisp special form.  While some questions about `commands` (aka interactive functions) will also be about "function" `interactive`, and some questions about `interactive` will also be about commands, the two are not the same thing.

Another tag might be `interactivity`, which would deal with questions involving different ways to interact with users.  (It would not be limited to dealing with commands.)  But that is quite general, and it might be better to stick with tags for different kinds or topics of interactivity (`mouse`, `menus`, `key-sequence`,...).

Comment: I think `interactive-function` might be misinterpreted as referring just to the `(interactive ...spec...)` special thingy, so I think `interactive-functions` (note the final `s`) would be ever so slightly better.

Answer (score -1):

I would be inclined to go with [commands](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commands) or [interactive](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive) (To mirror function definition).

Comment: I would not use "interactive" for the reasons Drew has elaborated upon.